# Error "The OutputPath property is not set for project" VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, asp.net-core-mvc, buildconfiguration

I have multiple projects in visual studio 2015. I am running my project in "ANY CPU" in debug mode. when I am trying to Run my project, I get the following error:

> The OutputPath property is not set for project '.csproj'.   Please
>   check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination
>   of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'
>   Platform='x64'.
>   This error may also appear if some other project is
>   trying to follow a project-to-project reference to this project, this
>   project has been unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the
>   referencing project does not build using the same or an equivalent
>   Configuration or Platform.    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Comment: Could you please provide a simple demo about the issue via OneDriver?

Comment: Thanks for your response @starain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just update the all the project solution into x64 then solution building fine.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was in the package

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.4.0

Nuget only fetched '`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.4.0.nupkg`' and didnt add the folders '`build`', and '`tools`'. And therefore didn't have '`Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props`'.

Once added from an backup (didnt help restoring), I just rebuilt the project and it worked like a charm!

Wasn't the most obvious error-message.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this! I had this happen a few months ago, when I upgraded the SF packages, and it happened now again.

Answer (score 0):

May by you mean "ANY CPU" is the solution configuration? Enter to "**Build\Configuration Manager**" and check "Configuration" and "Platform" for you '.csproj'.
Also try to check "`<OutputPath></OutputPath>`" in all of you cs project files.
Also look which platform will be set if `$(Platform)` is null:

```
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU(may be x64 here)</Platform>
```